# Where can I find a sandboxed version of ie9?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, sandbox

I'd like to install ie9, but I want to keep my ie8 for web devellopment purposes. How can I do that ?

Also, if it is possible for others version of IE (6, 7, 8), I would be happy.

Answer (score 0):

best way would be to create a virtual machine.  Due to how IE is designed, it integrates with the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem for developers.  IE does not support parallel installations.  The best solution is to install a virtual machine.  There are several free VM software products, I enjoy using [VirutalBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

You will also need a windows OS.  There is a 90 day Trial of W[indows 7 Enterprise](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495) available to IT professionals for testing.